# Centering header text horizontally on an <a> tag with role="button"

Tags: html, css, button, anchor

I am new to html and stack overflow. I'm now taking a course that focuses on the bootstrap framework. Is there a way of centering a header text within an a tag that has been assigned a role="button"?

I tried using regular text and the text appears where I want it but the font weight is too light. I tried making it bold with  but that makes it too heavy. The h6 tag gave me the ideal weight but I'm unable to center it horizontally, as it appears up top. Preferably, I'd like to use bootstrap if it's possible.

Below is my current code:

```
<div class="col col-sm align-self-center">
          <a href="#reservationForm" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-sm p-2" role="button"><h6 class="text-center">Reserve Table</h6></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

you can use text alignment classes from [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

```
<div class="col col-sm align-self-center text-center">
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with: `a` is `inline` element and `h6` is `block` element. `Block` elements are not valid inside of `inline` elements.

Put your `a` inside of `h6` and use Bootstrap class [`text-center`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/) on `h6`;

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
    <div class="col col-sm align-self-center">
        <h6 class="text-center">
          <a href="#reservationForm" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-sm p-2" role="button">
            Reserve Table
          </a>
        </h6>
    </div>
</header>
```

*This example is based on Bootstrap v4.5*

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked well. And thanks for the reminder on block and inline elements 